# How to implement hierarchical RBAC in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rbac, laravel-permission

I already checked the Laravel-permission by Spatie but I can not find a native way to implement the concept of parent role which inherent child role permissions. I was using such concept in Yii2 but I can not able o switch such feature to Laravel.
I there is a Laravel package with able to do this I will be appreciate or if there is a way to do it manually also ok. Here is how it is implemented in Yii2 framework [Yii2 autherization](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could define child [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies) as an either-or condition of several parent [Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#gates).

There's also [Gate:before](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#intercepting-gate-checks) actions that seem designed with Admin privileges in mind.